wordpress "Content is blocked", and all pages redirecting to a single page, including wp-admin and wp-login
Client's site completely broken today. Possibly when I added a txt file to the DNS area, in an attempt to link it to Google workspace. I have since deleted the txt file, but the site is still broken.
the site in question is https://avenaleisure.com/
it consistently redirects to /lander/ a page I was playing with to make popups for the client
Here is what I have tried in order to fix it:
Removed txt file
Edited htaccess: changed from
Order deny,allow
deny from all
to
Order allow,deny
Restored older backup: MySQL 7/10/24 Directory 7/8/24
Htaccess edited to a default state
Restored older backup: MySQL 7/7/24 Directory 7/8/24
in C Panel I have disabled ALL plugins and activated 2024 theme
the site is still broken and I have no idea how to access it.
Unfortunately this is a site I have inherited just a few days ago, I did not set it up, but I do have access to the control panel. Please help!

So what does your http server's error log file say?

Are you saying you yourself created the /lander/ page/route? The status code for the root URL is 200, the redirect happens via JavaScript. And the response comes with a cookie like expiry_partner=enom.ACTIVE.5D3C3...DDF874F; caf_ipaddr=XXX; country=YYY; city=ZZZ; lander_type=parking-enom-active - so to me this looks like you got trouble with your domain being "parked" by the provider.

https://support.enom.com/support/solutions/articles/201000065348-renewing-your-domain#h_01ER5BP1MJJF55DG9Y51JW3MQB says, "When a domain shows as expired in our system but displays a future date on WHOIS, the domain is expired. This is because the registrar in charge of the TLD has not received payment for the domain. The domain becomes inactive, the website is replaced with a parking page" - - you say you have access to the control panel, so I'd go and check for anything like that in there.

CBroe was correct, the domain register payment had lapsed with no warning to me. lander is a holding page created by enom to redirect a lapsed domain ( had made a page 'landing' but couldn't see any content so got convinced I had called in 'lander'). Nameservers are resolving now and hopefully all solved.
